# Inserting Video with Image Border into ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I have using code:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i 111.mp4 -vf "movie=1111.mp4[inner]; [in][inner] overlay=shortest=1:x=480:y=240 [out]" -c:v libx264 completed.mkv
```

Insert `main_video` into `backgroud_Video` but I can not seem to add a border image into this video.

An example of what I am aiming to do can be found [here on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-_35hHWSbk).

Is there any way to do this using ffmpeg?

Comment: Your YouTube link is broken

Answer (score 1):

Use the pad filter.

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 \
       -vf "movie=bg.mp4,hue=s=0[bg];[in]scale=iw/2:-1,pad=iw+20:ih+20:10:10:color=yellow[m]; \
           [bg][m]overlay=shortest=1:x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2[out]" -c:v libx264 completed.mkv
```

This creates a 10-pixel yellow border around the smaller video. `iw+20` and `ih+20` create a padded canvas which is 20 pixels bigger than the video. Then the video is placed at (10,10) from the top-left in the canvas, thus creating a uniform 10 pixel border, whose color is set to `yellow`.

Comment: Thank you so much, but help me select main_video into center backgroud_video
Thank

Comment: What's the resolution for main and BG video?

Comment: Main_video 1280x720 and backgroud_video 1280x720

Comment: and main_video inside backgroud_video size will be set =50% size video original!

Comment: See edited cmd.

Comment: Thank man, that great support, if i want resize video main i'll edit command  ?

Comment: To resize main video, edit the `scale` parameters.

Comment: Thank Mulvya you're super man, and i want question i want change corlor video_backgroud to black and white, can you help me do this

Comment: Edited command - added hue filter.