# Overlay Video and Insert video background looping with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

i have read a posts:

> [Inserting Video with Image Border into ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/1081471/inserting-video-with-image-border-into-ffmpeg)

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 \
-af "atempo=2.0,volume=1.5"\
-vf "setpts=PTS/2.0,movie=bg.mp4,hue=s=0[bg];[in]scale=iw/2:-,pad=iw+20:ih+20:10:10:color=yellow[m]; \
[bg][m]overlay=shortest=1:x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2[out]" -c:v libx264 completed.mkv
```

- I want to adjust the speed of video and audio to 2.0?
- And "movie=bg.mp4" looping?
- My input:

> main.mp4 --> 1h30' / 
>     bg.mp4   --> 30s

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4
       -vf "movie=bg.mp4:loop=200,hue=s=0[bg];
           [in]setpts=PTS/2,scale=iw/2:-1,pad=iw+20:ih+20:10:10:color=yellow[m];
           [bg][m]overlay=shortest=1:x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2"
       -af "atempo=2.0,volume=1.5" -c:v libx264 completed.mkv
```

Comment: I get `movie=C:\Users\Projects\data\potato.jpg:loop=200: Invalid argument`

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1297457/