# Overlay Video with ffmpeg Got a lot of dropping

Tags: ffmpeg

i just use this code founded in [Overlay Video and Insert video background looping with ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/1115382/overlay-video-and-insert-video-background-looping-with-ffmpeg?newreg=7b26ef7dcf5d420a94ad041bc7a4e5ac)

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4
   -vf "movie=bg.mp4:loop=200,hue=s=0[bg];
       [in]setpts=PTS/2,scale=iw/2:-1,pad=iw+20:ih+20:10:10:color=yellow[m];
       [bg][m]overlay=shortest=1:x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2"
   -af "atempo=2.0,volume=1.5" -c:v libx264 completed.mkv
```

but i get a lot of dropping frames :

```
frame=  578 fps= 14 q=24.0 size=   30585kB time=00:00:19.24 bitrate=13019.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=499 speed=
frame=  578 fps= 13 q=24.0 size=   30585kB time=00:00:19.24 bitrate=13019.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=525 speed=0.448
frame=  578 fps= 13 q=24.0 size=   30585kB time=00:00:19.24 bitrate=13019.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=553 speed=0.443x
Past duration 0.999992 too large
frame=  579 fps= 13 q=24.0 size=   30585kB time=00:00:19.24 bitrate=13019.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=577 speed=0.438x
frame=  579 fps= 13 q=24.0 size=   30585kB time=00:00:19.24 bitrate=13019.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=609 speed=0.433x
frame=  579 fps= 13 q=24.0 size=   30585kB time=00:00:19.24 bitrate=13019.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=637 speed=0.428x
frame=  579 fps= 13 q=24.0 size=   30585kB time=00:00:19.24 bitrate=13019.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=670 speed=0.423x
frame=  579 fps= 13 q=24.0 size=   30585kB time=00:00:19.24 bitrate=13019.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=701 speed=0.418x
frame=  579 fps= 12 q=24.0 size=   30585kB time=00:00:19.24 bitrate=13019.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=728 speed=0.414x
frame=  579 fps= 12 q=24.0 size=   30585kB time=00:00:19.24 bitrate=13019.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=756 speed=0.409x
frame=  579 fps= 12 q=-1.0 Lsize=   35007kB time=00:00:19.29 bitrate=14863.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=783 speed=0.406x
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? That command speeds up the main video and desaturates the BG. Do you need the same thing? Show the properties of your two videos using `ffprobe video.mp4`

Comment: First thank you for editing my post and replying , i want to achieve the same thing as this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yph83IzlHcE) , without desaturate the BG and without speed up the main video , but as i said i got a lot of dropping frames , and i tested with different videos and format , i want to use it  for a lot of my videos

Comment: Frames will be dropped with the original command because main video is sped up 2x but framerate isn't changed, so half the frames have to be dropped. Try modified cmd in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4
-filter_complex "movie=bg.mp4:loop=200,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[bg];
   [0]scale=iw/2:-1,pad=iw+20:ih+20:10:10:color=yellow[m];
   [bg][m]overlay=shortest=1:x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2"
-c:v libx264 completed.mkv
```

You may have to tweak the scale arguments based on the relative sizes of your videos.

Comment: Thank you sir , it work fine now without any problem , i will post another code that i have problem with in another question , thank you so much again

Comment: another think ; i want to apply  a noise.mp3 all over the video ,i know it will be added with amix , but i have no clue how as the code is become more compliacated for me  , thx