# Cannot get stabilization file to render to a path I specify

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to do some stabilization and I'm bumping up against what I think is a limitation or bug, but I wanted to get further clarification from experts. I can't get the transform file to appear anywhere except the location where the FFMPEG.exe file is located (the same folder I'm currently running the exe from).

I'm attempting to render out my transform file to a sepcific path on my machine. Here's the call I'm making:

ffmpeg.exe -i "C:\LocalTemp\DealerVision\DealerVision.MediaProcessing.Video.Combine.Combiner\372e538c-df1b-4355-bc9a-43e27899b9ee\11474_1.mp4" -vf vidstabdetect=show=1:shakiness=5:accuracy=8:result="C:\LocalTemp\DealerVision\DealerVision.MediaProcessing.Video.Combine.Combiner\372e538c-df1b-4355-bc9a-43e27899b9ee\11474_1.trf" -f null -

This successfully generates a file, but it puts it in the same path as the FFMPEG.exe file. It also renames the file "LocalTempDealerVisionDealerVision.MediaProcessing.Video.Combine.Combiner372e538c-df1b-4355-bc9a-43e27899b9ee11474_1.trf"

So it appears it's stripping out my path and just making a new name for the transform based upon the path I fed it. How do I go about rendering out this transform file to a location of *my* choice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to single-quote and escape the path

```
result='c\:\\path\\vidstab.trf'
```